# Excluding fields from @Embedded properties on case by case basis with Hibernate/JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, annotations

I am migrating some classes in a Hibernate hbm.xml file to JPA annotations.

We have an embeddable class `Address` that is used in several places. Each place uses a different subset of the properties in Address.

(getters/setters omitted for brevity)

```
@Embeddable
public class Address {
  String email;
  String address;
  String city; 
  String state;
  String zip;
  String country;
}

@Entity
@Table(name="customer")
public class Customer {
  @Embedded
  @AttributeOverrides({
    @AttributeOverride(name="address", column=@Column(name="ship_addr"),
    @AttributeOverride(name="city", column=@Column(name="ship_city"),
    @AttributeOverride(name="state", column=@Column(name="ship_state"),
    @AttributeOverride(name="zip", column=@Column(name="ship_zip"),
    @AttributeOverride(name="country", column=@Column(name="ship_country")
  })
  Address shippingAddress;

  @Embedded
  @AttributeOverrides({
    @AttributeOverride(name="address", column=@Column(name="bill_addr"),
    @AttributeOverride(name="city", column=@Column(name="bill_city"),
    @AttributeOverride(name="state", column=@Column(name="bill_state"),
    @AttributeOverride(name="zip", column=@Column(name="bill_zip")
  })
  Address billingAddress;
}
```

Note that in this contrived example, shippingAddress uses Address.country, but billingAddress does not; and neither of them use Address.email.

The problem is that Hibernate is inferring `@Column` tags for any column where I haven't explicitly provided one.

I tried adding `@Transient` to all the `Address` fields, but it appears that `@AttributeOverride` does not trump `@Transient`.

Is there any workaround for this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think it is possible with annotations to "ignore" a field from address in your embedded objects.

A workaround is to create a base type Address without email and an ExtendedAddress (subclass of Address) with the field email.

Comment: The problem is that this is a common model class used all over our organization. I'm searching for a way to migrate this class to JPA without changing behavior, or forcing 30 different teams to adjust their code.

Comment: Note also that this is an issue with JPA's switch to opt-out using &at;Transient, rather than opt-in using &at;Column. The idea was to make adopting JPA less invasive by not requiring &at;Column annotations everywhere--this is just a side effect that has bitten us and made it impossible to migrate this one class from legacy XML configuration to JPA annotations.

Comment: If you can't change your model, than I don't see a solution.
You will just have to ignore the properties of Address that aren't used, and thus leave them blank in the DB. Dirty solution, but the least invasive.

Answer (score 8):

My advice would be to create a new entity called PartialAddress/NationalAddress/BillingAddress. This would be used only for the JPA mapping, and not exposed on the Customer interface:

```
private PartialAddress billingAddress;

public Address getBillingAddress() {
    return billingAddress.toAddress();
}
```

Otherwise, I have come up with a somewhat ugly workaround for this problem, maybe it will work for you as well. Instead of mapping the field to a real column, I return a SQL null constant:

```
@Embedded
@AttributeOverrides({
    @AttributeOverride(name="address", column=@Column(name="bill_addr"),
    @AttributeOverride(name="city", column=@Column(name="bill_city"),
    @AttributeOverride(name="state", column=@Column(name="bill_state"),
    @AttributeOverride(name="zip", column=@Column(name="bill_zip"),
    @AttributeOverride(name="country", column=@Column(name="bill_id + null"),
})
Address billingAddress;
```

I'm using Oracle and EclipseLink, works on Hibernate 3.6 as well. And I've only tested it on read-only objects. Though, theoretically, setting the `insertable` and `updatable` attributes to false should be enough.

Comment: This is a very nice and innovative workaround .  I directly map the ignored property to null (i.e `column=@Column(name="null")`

Comment: @KenChan 's workaround is acceptable for persisting data, but there is a problem when reading from the data base. It generetes an "javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet" and the message says: "o.h.e.j.s.SqlExceptionHelper - ERROR: column not found tabl0_.null"

Comment: @KenChan simply entering NULL did not work for me on Oracle 12. However gfonte's original solution did.