# With JPA 2.0, how can one specify that a property/attribute of an embedded object as not persistent?

Tags: jpa, persistence, eclipselink, jpa-2.0, spring-data-jpa

So, I have an object that is embedded via the `@Embedded` annotation in several entities. I would like to exclude a property/attribute from being persisted in one instance where it is embedded but not the other. Is there a concise way to do this? Should I do this? If not, why not? I'm using spring-data-jpa 1.7.1, eclipselink 2.5.1. Thanks in advance!

Ken

Comment: Check this post: [Excluding fields from @Embedded properties on case by case basis with Hibernate/JPA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7016380/excluding-fields-from-embedded-properties-on-case-by-case-basis-with-hibernate)

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you cannot use annotations if you want to persist a field of a class (whether embedded or otherwise) differently in one place than another (since an annotation is specified in one place only), or at least I can't see how it would be possible.

Secondly, with XML you could specify an "embedded" element and under that "attributes" and for each attribute you could put "transient". Never tried it mind, but that would be the way I'd go

Comment: Thanks for taking a stab at it Neil! Yeah, I don't think I can do what I was trying to do. Regardless, we decided on a different direction. Thanks!