# How to exclude a column from @Embeddable?

Tags: java, hibernate

Is it possible to exclude a column from `@Embeddable` classes?

Like:

```
@Entity
public class Customer {
    @Embedded(exclude = "state") //of course this is does not exists
    private Address address;
}

@Embeddable
public class Address {
        private String street;
        private String city;
        private String state;
    private String town;
    //ect
}
```

Comment: I have to say that I don't see much value in being able to do so. Just let the attribute be *nullable* and don't set it.

Comment: I think the question similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7016380/excluding-fields-from-embedded-properties-on-case-by-case-basis-with-hibernate

Comment: OK so I'll probably have to create a partial embeddable from it, and nest the partial into my current `Address`.

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried to put the filed as Transient : http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/Transient.html ?
This could do the trick, but the field will be excluded for every classes that embeds the class.

If you want to ignore it in only in this class, then it will not be enough :)

Regards,

Comment: I just want to ignore it within  a specific class, not globally.